# Management Studio 2012 Backward Compatibility

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-tools

Two quick questions for anybody that's tried this:

1. Will Management Studio 2012 install and run side-by-side with, say, Management Studio 2008? I vaguely recall not being able to do this with 2008 and 2005.
2. Does Management Studio 2012 fully support connecting to and administering SQL Server 2008? Does Intellisense still work against older versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. I have had no problems with it.
2. No problems there either. Intellisense works against 2008 (not 2005 of course).

Comment: Cool. Sounds like I can safely dive into 2012 Developer Edition, then. Addendum: Does shift+space still select the whole row in the table data editor? That drives me right up the wall.

Comment: @db2 - Never noticed that little feature but yes it does.

Comment: Aw, man. Oh well, can't win 'em all. :)

Comment: Don't forget that SQL Server 2012 SSMS the lowest level server it can connect to is SQL Server 2005. Big difference between that and the 2008 versions.

Comment: @SQLChicken - Interesting. I don't use SQL Server 2000 that much but connecting with SSMS executing queries works just fine. Perhaps there are some other management stuff that does not work?